# Take a group of numbers put them in 3 new groups evenly

Tags: c#, linq, xamarin

To explain in more detail. I need to take a bunch of numbers and place them in classes/groups. Lets say I have 100 numbers. I need to divide that by the number of classes (n) where n = 3 and place them in three groups with 33, 33, 34 numbers respectively. or if (n) = 4 then it would be 4 classes of 25, 25, 25, 25. They also need to stay grouped from highest to lowest.

I have searched and saw a few things relating to LINQ to do this but I haven't wrapped my head around it.

I figured I could put all the numbers in a list, then find the total number in the index divide it by the number of classes to find out how many need to go into each class. My problem comes in is how to pull the numbers out of the list and place them in there respective groups while maintaining there grouping highest to lowest. Result desired for 3 classes with 15 numbers.

```
 List<int> test = new List<int> { 100, 99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, 90, 89, 88, 87, 86 };
        int total_indexes = test.Count + 1;
        float classes = (total_indexes / 3);
```

Classes would equal 5 so it would look like this below

Class A:
100
99
98
97
96

Class B:
95
94
93
92
91

Class C:
90
89
88
87
86

Comment: `int total_indexes = test.Count + 1;` what is this meaning of this?

Comment: What did you tried. You will learn more if you try it yourself. Show the code and if it isn't working, we'll give some ideas. Some may provide a solution, but will it help you.

Comment: Its to give me the total number of numbers to put into the class. And it might not even be necessary if Linq can evenly split the list into the equal groups. I just think I'm adding to many steps whenever Linq can handle everything. Its just I have zero experience with how LINQ works.

Comment: What is the desired result if you have `10` items and `4` groups?  `{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8, 9, 10}` or something else?

Comment: Here a tip: `test.GroupBy(i => KEY, i => i);`. Replace the `KEY` with code that returns the same value for these numbers `100, 99, 98, 97, 96` and for `95, 94, 93, 92, 91` a different value. What about a little formule..

Comment: Dmitry that looks correct. the tailing unequal group at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I wrote this piece of code to give you the result you want:

```
public List<int[]> Do(int[] numbers, int groupCount)
    {
        numbers = numbers.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToArray();

        var result = new List<int[]>();

        var itemsCountInEachGroup = numbers.Length / groupCount;
        var remainingCount = numbers.Length % groupCount;

        var iterateCount = groupCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < iterateCount; i++)
        {
            var skip = i * itemsCountInEachGroup;
            //Last iterate
            if (i == iterateCount - 1)
            {
                var n = numbers.Skip(skip).Take(itemsCountInEachGroup + remainingCount).ToArray();
                result.Add(n);
            }
            else
            {
                var n = numbers.Skip(skip).Take(itemsCountInEachGroup).ToArray();
                result.Add(n);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Example =>

```
var numbers = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 };
var res = Do(numbers, 5);
```

Comment: My first time seeing Dictionary. from other examples of dictionary they access it by res.StartCollecting()  but that is missing so what would be the proper way to get values from the first array inside the dictionary? apologize If i asked this the wrong way.

Comment: I updated my answer to use List instead of Dictionary.

Comment: just messing around with different things I came up with this and it seemed to work somewhat. but the second array only had one number foreach (var number in res[0])
            {
                await DisplayAlert("test", "Group 1 - " + number.ToString(), "Okay");
            }

            foreach (var number in res[1])
            {
                await DisplayAlert("test", "Group 2 - " + number.ToString(), "Okay");
            }

Answer (score 0):

This solution is probably not very optimized, and is likely to be improved.

```
        int groupNb = 3, elementNb = 100;

        //Populating elements with pseudo-random numbers for demonstration  
        Random r = new Random();
        List<int> elements = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < elementNb; i++)
            elements.Add(r.Next(0, 100));

        //The groups
        List<int>[] groups = new List<int>[groupNb];

        //Classifying elements in groups             
        int currentGroup = 0;
        foreach (int value in elements.OrderByDescending(x => x))
        {
            if (groups[currentGroup] == null)
                groups[currentGroup] = new List<int>();

            groups[currentGroup].Add(value);
            currentGroup = ++currentGroup % groupNb;
        }
```

Comment: I tried this but I'm using Xamarin and the stack.TryPop says stack<int> does not contain a definition

Comment: I don't know xamarin very well. I updated my answer with a version that do not use Stack class.

Answer (score 0):

I did the answer with a PowerShell
open PowerShell ISE
and write the following script:

```
$Numbers = 100,94,91,90,89,85,84,81,79,74,74,70,95,92,83
$SortedNumbers = $Numbers | sort -Descending
$NumberofClasses = 3
$Countofnumbersinclase = $Numbers.Count / $NumberofClasses
$x = 0
$y = 0
For ($i = 0 ; $i -lt $NumberofClasses ;$i++){
$y = $i+$Countofnumbersinclase-1+$y
$Clasno = $i+1
Write-host "class No $Clasno is " $SortedNumbers[$X..$Y]
$x = $y+1
}
```

The result as following:

class No 1 is  100 95 94 92 91
class No 2 is  90 89 85 84 83
class No 3 is  81 79 74 74 70

I think exactly s you want and you can add any numbers or any no of classes and it will works

Answer (score 0):

If *all groups* (with the only exception of the last one) should have *equal* number of items you can try *Linq* `OrderBy` followed by `GroupBy`:

**Code:**

```
using System.Linq;

...

private static List<T>[] Classify<T>(List<T> source, int count)
  where T : IComparable<T> {
 
  int size = source.Count / count;

  return source
    .OrderBy(item => item)
    .Select((item, index) => new { item, index })
    .GroupBy(pair => Math.Clamp(pair.index / size, 0, count - 1), 
             pair => pair.item)
    .Select(group => group.ToList())
    .ToArray();
}
```

If your C# version doesn't have `Math.Clamp` you can implement it as

```
private static int Clamp(int value, int min, int max) {
  return value < min ? min :
         value > max ? max :
         value;        
}
```

**Demo:**

```
  // Let's split "count" items into "classes" classes
  int count = 10;
  int classes = 4; 

  List<int> demo = Enumerable
    .Range(1, count)
    .ToList();

  var result = Classify(demo, classes);

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
    .Select(list => $"{list.First()} - {list.Last()} ({list.Count} items) : {string.Join(", ", list)}")); 

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
1 - 2 (2 items) : 1, 2
3 - 4 (2 items) : 3, 4
5 - 6 (2 items) : 5, 6
7 - 10 (4 items) : 7, 8, 9, 10
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry this works as well. I'm not sure which answer is more efficient or faster I'll have to do some testing.

Comment: I have one last question for you. those are ascending groups and numbers how could I create the groups from highest to lowest number? Lastly after I have done that I need the first three highest values of each group ( Group 1: 100 99 98 |  Group 2: 95 94 93 | Group: 3  90 89 88  because I have to do a math formula like 100 x 60% - 99 x 40% and 98 x 20% on each of the top three in each group

Comment: @Brian Palmer: change `OrderBy` into `OrderByDescending` and you'll have classes in descending order

Comment: Okay so it has the orderbydescending code. Thanks!